# How to change the for loop into filter method?

Tags: javascript

I have created the menu cards using the inputs from the user. In the cards , I want to filter the cards by using their dish name and display = 'none' the other cards. The filtering should happen when the filter button is clicked. My code is below. I iterated the cards using for loop. But i want to do it by filter method and without using for loop.

```js
const breakfastBtn = document.querySelector('.breakfast-btn');

breakfastBtn.addEventListener('click', filterBreakFast);

function filterBreakFast(){
    let type = cardsContainer.querySelectorAll('.card-length')
  
    for ( let i = 0; i < type.length; i++ ) {
        let span = type[i].querySelector('.card-dish-type');
        if ( span.innerHTML.indexOf('Brunch') > -1 ) {
            type[i].style.display = "initial";
        } else {
            type[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why would you use `filter`? are you going to use the filtered array for something? seems like `.forEach` is more relevant to your code - which is handy since the node list returned by `querySelectorAll` has a `forEach` method

Comment: `cardsContainer.querySelectorAll('.card-length').forEach(type => type.style.display = type.querySelector('.card-dish-type').innerHTML.includes('Brunch') ? "initial" : "none";`

Comment: `.filter()` is used to create an array with only the filtered items, but in your case it seems that you only need/want to process the items (i.e modify each item) so if you just want to avoid the `for loop` you can use `.forEach()`.

Answer (score 1):

For already working code that you would like to be reviewed, you might find a better response at [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

If your only intention is to avoid using a `for` loop, this is an example of your code rewritten with array methods. The `.filter` method is probably not what you're looking for in this instance. `.filter` returns another array filtered based on a function. What it seems you intend to do is apply two different actions based on whether or not the html of an element includes the string "Brunch".

We can use the `.forEach` array method instead of a `for... in` loop, though it's mostly a stylistic change.

```js
const breakfastBtn = document.querySelector('.breakfast-btn');

breakfastBtn.addEventListener('click', filterBreakFast);

function filterBreakFast() {
    const type = cardsContainer.querySelectorAll('.card-length');
    type.forEach(element => {
        const span = element.querySelector(".card-dish-type");
        const hasBrunch = span.innerHTML.includes("Brunch");
        if (hasBrunch) { 
            element.style.display = "initial";
        } else { 
            element.style.display = "none";
        }
    });
}
```